# How to have a C# object available outside and inside an MVC .NET C# application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC .NET C# application and I need to have an instance of an object available through the entire scope of the MVC app and also outside of it.

The object is an instance of a custom C# class I made.

It has to be the same instance of this object, can't instantiate an instance outside and another one inside the MVC app.

So the object has to be avaiable at this scope (that's my definition of "outside the MVC app framework)":

```
    var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                          .UseKestrel()
                          .UseUrls("http://*:80")
                          .UseStartup<Api.Hosting.Startup>()
                          .UseHttpSys()
                          .Build();
    host.RunAsync();
```

That's easily done by instantiating it:

```
    var obj = new MyClass();

    // here make use of the obj instance
    obj.DoSomething();

    var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                          .UseKestrel()
                          .UseUrls("http://*:80")
                          .UseStartup<Api.Hosting.Startup>()
                          .UseHttpSys()
                          .Build();
    host.RunAsync();
```

but now how can I use the same object inside the MVC app (I mean, at the controller level, at the services level and so on...)

Comment: There are plenty of options... I would just use some sort of a MemoryCache shared between inside and outside.

Comment: When you are talking about "outside the app" do you mean in a separate application (eg a console app or service)?

Comment: @Chris ehrn no, when I say "outside the app" I mean as in the example above, before instantiating and running the WebHost

Comment: Ah, sorry. I've not done anything with AspNetCore so hadn't actually recognised what you were doing there. It may be worth tagging it more specifically as asp.net-core or whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a great use case for use of dependency injection.  .NET Core treats DI as a first class citizen within the framework (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) and it is pretty highly configurable to give you the opportunity for fine control over the lifetime of objects.  In your `ConfigureServices` method, you would add the following code to have the single instance of your object that you created in the code example made available to the MVC application:

`services.AddSingleton<MyClass>(obj);`

Within the MVC application, you are best off to use constructor injection on your controllers to provide the Singleton instance, but if there is some constraint of the current implementation, it's possible to access the instance through the  `HttpRequest.RequestServices` object - using it essentially as a Service Locator.  Again - you're MUCH better off to use constructor injection here and not take an unneeded dependency on the HttpRequest.

Comment: Ok, I added the AddSingleton() method passing my object, but now how do I pass this object from the outside? I am missing this last bit. The method ConfigureService() accepts only 1 parameter

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini - I think that you may be focused on wanting to handle the actual creation of the Singleton object inside your Main method, but ideally that method is only going to request a webhost and call its Run method. The triggering of the Singleton objects creation and preparation for use would be done in the ConfigureServices method.  This could be accomplished by instantiating the singleton and calling the DoSomething() method (assuming it does something necessary to establish initial state), but it would be cleaner to create an AddMyObject extension method on IServiceCollection